# Items in SpinWheelSlot are not displayed correctly

Tags: dojo, dojox.mobile

I am developing a mobile application using the Dojo Toolkit. I have the following code:

```
<div id="spin1" data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.SpinWheel">
    <div id="sortOrderSlot" data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.SpinWheelSlot"
         items="['pt','px','cm']" style="width: 100%;">
    </div>
</div>
```

The output should be as follows:

```
----------------------------
-                          -
-            pt            -
-                          -
-            px            -
-                          -
-            cm            -
-                          -
----------------------------
```

But I get following result:

```
----------------------------
-                          -
-            p             -
-                          -
-            t             -
-                          -
-            ,             -
-                          -
-            p             -
-                          -
-            x             -
-                          -
-            ,             -
-                          -
-            c             -
-                          -
-            m             -
-                          -
----------------------------
```

I first thought it would be a defect of the browser, but it looks the same in every browser. What is the problem with that?

Answer (score 0):

The value of "items" is an array of [key,value] pairs. In your case you must use "labels". In addition you should now use "data-dojo-props" to specify widget attributes.

So this should work better:

```
<div data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.SpinWheelSlot"
     data-dojo-props="labels: ['pt','px','cm']" style="text-align:center;width:100%;">
</div>
```